# Getting values of dynamically created UserControls (VB.NET)

Tags: string, vb.net, user-controls

So I'm currently working on my thesis for this S.Y. 
It's sort of a local thesis library program and I'm currently on the "adding books" part. I'm trying to make it more user friendly by making it work like this site
https://www.citethisforme.com/cite/sources/journalmanualcite

Sooo...

I'm using a UserControl named *uc_contributor* to input the different names of the authors (*It has 5 textboxes and 2 buttons*). [(uc_contributor design)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6BbZ.png). It is then added to a panel inside another UserControl named *uc_add* by clicking a button. [(what it looks like during runtime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Rp3.png)

I was wondering how can I store the values of the textboxes in every instance of uc_contributor
to a declared variable (to hopefully add into a database).

Comment: Why do you want a single string?

Comment: I don't necessarily need it to be stored into a single string, I'm open to suggestions. Maybe an array or something else?

Comment: You need to think about how your database will be structured and then decide how your data should be configured to easily insert into the database.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can proceed? I'm using MS Access as my database.

Comment: If you are not already familiar with ADO.net, now is the time to learn. Create a table with fields to hold your data. You could use a DataGridView which is easy to update to the database when bound to a datatable.